# Specifying the start and end on a binary value in Python

Tags: python, types, binary, hex

I am handling binary values in Python.
Let's say I have -

```
1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101
```

and I want to specify the start and end point among this line, slice it and store them separately in different variables.

Is there a way to break binary values into sections in Python?

Input/Output example:
Input

```
data = '1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101'
```

Output

```
a = 10000
b = 001
c = 0000
d = 1011
e = 11100
f = 01100
g = 10
h = 0000
i = 1100
j = 10101011
k = 00111101
```

Comment: sections of what length? aka how many bits

Comment: I want to divide them into about 11 sections, some being 1 bit, some (the longest) being 8 bit, some being 3,4,or 5bit..
Say I want to divide them into something like 

10000 00 1 0000 1011 11 100011 001 00000 1100 10101011 00111101

Comment: maybe i get you wrong but can't you just use:  a = int(var[2:4], 2)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I just wanted to mention the data type but I will delete that part

Comment: Can you give a simple input-output example?

Comment: The example is still not clear. What it is the data type? Byte array? String? How do we know where we want to break it up?

Answer (score 0):

If your binary value is in a string, and you have a list of lengths you would like to take from it, you can iterate and chop off those lengths from the front of the string as follows —

```
data = '1000000100001011111000110010000011001010101100111101'
lengths = [5,3,4,4,5,5,2,4,4,8,8]
chunks = []

for l in lengths:
    chunk, data = data[:l], data[l:]
    chunks.append(chunk)
```

This would give you the following in `chunks`

```
['10000',
 '001',
 '0000',
 '1011',
 '11100',
 '01100',
 '10',
 '0000',
 '1100',
 '10101011',
 '00111101']
```